# Why does mkdir take 100 seconds sometimes with USB flash drive?

Tags: usb

I'm measuring up to 100 seconds (not a typo) for `mkdir` to a USB flash drive using Pi B+. The vast majority of the time it's 20 to 40 mS using a bash script, but sometimes a few seconds, and once in a while, 100 seconds. The CPU usage is very low, only a few percent. I'm running 4.1.7+ #817 PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:25:36 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux, but I've seen multiple seconds per `mkdir` on other machines with other versions of the OS, when writing to a USB flash drive.

My guess is there's an issue writing to some blocks in the USB flash drive. The flash drive has low traffic, only about 10 MBytes/minute = 1.3 Mbits/second continuously. I've also seen some shutdowns pause longer than I expected; I've wondered if it's a flash memory issue.

How can I pin down where the delay is so I can fix this? Has anyone else noticed long write delays to usb flash drive?

Comment: It could be because another application has a lock on the directory or device which is slowing your directory creation down. Such as another script that is creating directorys aswell

Comment: Does there have to be a lock file, or would one application deleting directories and another application making directories at the same time conflict with one another ? BTW, the issue occurs more often as USB flash drives get older, measured in the number of times they have been completely written through. I think this is an unexplored facet of using a USB flash drive as a disk drive as opposed to occasionally storing a number of files there.

Comment: However, I've seen it even on micro SD cards, which are, of course, the disk for a Pi and countless mobile devices.